# I can't see the entire scrollbar

Tags: html, css

As I said on the title, i can't see the end of the scrollbar and i the final words doesn't appear.
You can see it in the picture
(https://i.stack.imgur.com/XUi89.png)

The dark-gray part is a iframe and also the withe is another iframe, this is because I need to redirect the page "Where to find us".

I probably got something else wrong, sorry but it's my first site a bit more difficult.

```css
html {
  overflow-y: hidden;
  height: 100%;
}

html,
body,
iframe {
  margin: 0px;
  padding: 0px;
  border: none;
}

.nav-bar {
  display: block;
  width: 100%;
  border: none;
  height: 107px;
}

.page {
  position: absolute;
  height: 100%;
  width: 100%;
  margin-bottom: 700px;
}

.page iframe {
  width: 100%;
  height: 100%;
}
```

```html
<!DOCTYPE html>

<head>
  <link rel="stylesheet" href="CSS/index.css">
</head>

<body>
  <iframe class="nav-bar" src="nav-bar.html" frameborder="0"></iframe>
  <div class="page">
    <iframe class="left" src="main.html" name="main" scrolling="si" frameborder="0"></iframe>
  </div>
</body>
```